# pass pk to CreateView form in django

Tags: python, django, materialize

i'm new to django.

I have a model that looks like this:

**models.py**

```
class Intervention(models.Model):
subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
begin_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
end_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
speaker = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
campus = models.ForeignKey(Campus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Intervention'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Interventions'

def __str__(self):
    return self.subject

class Evaluation(models.Model):
interventions = models.ForeignKey(Intervention, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
student_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
speaker_knowledge_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
speaker_teaching_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
speaker_answer_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
slide_content_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
slide_examples_mark = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20), MinValueValidator(0)])
comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

The idea is when that the student enter the website on home page he have to choose the campus where he study then he is redirected to a page where he see only interventions of his campus then when he choose the intervention he get the detail of it :

[Home page screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTGMS.png)

[Interventions page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYuRe.png)

[Intervetion detail page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEL3K.png)

Everything is working so far. Now on "intervention detail page" when the user click on "give mark" he is redirected to a page to create mark  (i use CreateView class-based) like below:

[create mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh3Hy.png)

Now my question is how can i replace  Modelchoicefield in the generated form by pk of the intervetion that student want to give a mark?

**Views.py**

```
class CreateEvaluationView(CreateView):
form_class = NewEvaluation
template_name = 'mark.html'
def home(request):
   campus = Campus.objects.all().order_by('-name')
return render(request, 'home.html', {'campus': campus})

def mark(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    campus = request.POST.get('campus')
    intervention = Intervention.objects.filter(campus=campus)
    return render(request, 'mark.html', {'intervention': intervention})

def intervention_detail(request, pk):
intervention_detail = get_object_or_404(Intervention, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'intervention_detail.html', {'intervention_detail': intervention_detail})
```

**urls.py**

```
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('mark/', views.mark, name='mark'),
path('mark/<int:pk>/', views.intervention_detail, name='intervention_detail'),
path('mark/create/', CreateEvaluationView.as_view(template_name="givemark.html"), name='newmark'),
path('intervention/create/', login_required(CreateInterventionView.as_view(template_name="intervention_create.html")), name='create'),
path('intervention/', login_required(ListInterventionView.as_view(template_name="intervention_list.html")), name='list'),
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Bast regards.

Comment: I prefer function over view class. It will be good choise using function as create page. Especially forms cannot help at all. I can prepare example code if that will solve your problem?

Comment: Can you post your `NewEvaluation` code? Also not sure how did you get `/mark/create/2` url - there are no same url patterns from your `urls.py`. I assume it's your intervetion pk?

Comment: sure! i was thinking about it since it looks hard to play with class-based views options

Comment: class NewEvaluation(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Evaluation
        fields = ('__all__')

Comment: Gasanov yes it's intervention pk.

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide `Intervention` pk to your form. Simplest solution would be to just pass it with url:

```
path('mark/create/<int:intervention_pk>', CreateEvaluationView.as_view(template_name="givemark.html"), name='newmark'),
```

It will require modification in your template to pass intervention pk, such as `reverse('newmark', intervention_pk=intervention.pk)`

Exclude intervention pk from your form, so your users will not be able to modify it accidentally.

```
class NewEvaluation(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Evaluation
        exclude = ('interventions',)
```

Set intervention pk right before you save your form:

```
class CreateEvaluationView(CreateView):
    form_class = NewEvaluation
    template_name = 'mark.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        intervention = Intervention.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['intervention_pk'])
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.interventions = intervention
        self.object.save()
```

Comment: Few notes: this url path is not very clear that it uses intervention pk - better to use like `/intervention/<pk>/mark/`. You don't need to explicitly declare form class - [`CreateView` can do it for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms), except it doesn't have `exclude`, you have to declare all required fields one by one. Why change of template name in `urls.py`?

Comment: Thanks @gasanov that's very helpfull i changed the urls as you suggested and it's much more clear now. But hen i try to create a mark i get this error Cannot assign "2": "Evaluation.interventions" must be a "Intervention" instance. do you have any idea?

Comment: thanks a lot i got it works and even redirect to /intervention/<pk>/ after new mark! now time to do AVG for each course and do some charts with chart.js.          Everytime i say "yeah now im good at django" i figure out that there's a lot more to learn!